# How to set Cookies at Http Get method using Java

Tags: java, http, cookies, get, forum

I want to do a manual GET with cookies in order to download and parse a web page. I need to extract the security token, in order to make a post at the forum. I have completed the login, have read the response and extracted the cookies (3 pairs of (name,value) ). I then wrote the String containing the cookies like this:

```
CookieString="name1=value1; name2=value2; name3=value3"
```

I then do the following

```
HttpURLConnection connection
connection = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(Link).openConnection());
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", CookieString );
connection.connect();
```

I then read the page but it shows that I am not logged at the forum. What am I doing wrong?

edit: I know that I must extract the security token if I want to make a post. My train of thought was that in order to extract it, I need to GET this particular page. But for the security token to be as a hidden field I must be online, thus I needed the cookies. But when I GET the page and I set the cookies as mentioned above i get the page as a guest, it shows that I am not online and the value of security token is guest which is not useful for me. I will check the link you gave  me and hopefully will find a solution.

Answer (score 15):

To be sure, you should be gathering the cookies from the response's `Set-Cookie` headers. To send them back in the subsequent requests, you should set them one by one using [`URLConnection#addRequestProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#addRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Basically:

```
// ...

// Grab Set-Cookie headers:
List<String> cookies = connection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");

// ...

// Send them back in subsequent requests:
for (String cookie : cookies) {
    connection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 2)[0]);
}

// ...
```

The `split(";", 2)` is there to get rid of cookie attributes which are irrelevant for the server side like `expires`, `path`, etc.

For a more convenienced HTTP client I'd suggest to have a look at [Apache HttpComponents Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/). It can handle all the cookie stuff more transparently.

#### See also:

- [How to use URLConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

---

**Update**: as per the comments, this is not a cookie problem. A wrong request token means that the server has CSRF/bot prevention builtin (to prevent people like you). You need to extract the token as a hidden input field from the requested page with the form and resend it as a request parameter. [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) may be useful to extract all (hidden) input fields. Don't forget to pass the name-value pair of the button as well which you'd like to "press" programmatically. Also see the abovementioned link for more hints.

In the future, you should really be more clear about the exact error you retrieve and not guess something in the wild. Copypaste the exact error message and so on.

Comment: That's what I do and it doesn't work. I read the cookies from the Response's Set-Cookie headers. I used to set them all together with the setRequestProperty. I tried one-by-one wuth the addRequestProperty but the result was the same. I can't find what I am doing wrong. 

I would prefer to avoid using a 3rd party library if that was possible.

Comment: Then the problem lies somewhere else. What is the URL? What does a HTTP tracker tool like Fiddler say?

Comment: The URL is a post reply page of a vbulletin forum. The strange thing is that when I use the cookies at the same link with a POST method to post a reply, the response is a page that says that I do not have a valid security token, but it sees that I am online, therefore the cookies work. When I try to GET the same page with the same cookies in order to extract the security token It asks me to log in. I will install fiddler, see how it works and will get back to you. If u have any ideas plz tell me.

Comment: FWIW, for people working on Android, I was recently trying to attach multiple cookies to a `UrlConnection` and discovered that `addRequestProperty()` doesn't actually add multiple headers of the same name. That observation might be wrong, but the only way I could get the server to recognize my multiple cookies was to join them into one `String`, separating them with `;`. Then setting that single `String` with `addRequestProperty()`/`setRequestProperty()` to the "Cookie" header as shown above. I seem to find conflicting info about what `addRequest...` and `setRequest...` actually do.

Comment: Tried this out and I believe the `cookie.split(";", 1)[0]` should be `cookie.split(";", 2)[0]` (the limit param indicates the number of pieces to return, where the final piece automatically takes up the remainder of the string).

Comment: calling addRequestProperty("Cookie", ".....") in a loop will result an invalid cookie header! see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55512910/httpurlconnection-addrequestproperty-with-cookie-resulting-in-comma-separated

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the cookie values are not hard-coded but obtained from a previous request, it's probably easiest to use the `CookieHandler` class.

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
```

Then your `HttpURLConnection` will automatically save any cookies it receives and send them back with the next request to the same host.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Grab Set-Cookie headers:
List<String> cookies = connection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");

// ...

// Send them back in subsequent requests:
for (String cookie : cookies) {
    connection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
}
```

Above code will work for sending multiple cookies just use setRequestProperty instead of addRequestProperty. The working code is:

```
// Grab Set-Cookie headers:
List<String> cookies = connection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");

// ...

// Send them back in subsequent requests:
for (String cookie : cookies) {
    connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
}
```