# Java equivalent of a python GET request?

Tags: java, python, http, get

I am trying to perform the same task in Java, but can't seem to figure out how to particularly set the cookies.

I know how to do this in python:

```
response = requests.get(app_url,cookies=cookies,allow_redirects=False)
```

How do I do the equivalent in Java?

Comment: You can use Java 11, and later, HTTP Client API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a URLConnection(`HttpURLConnection` or `HttpsURLConnection`, set the cookie and connect.

```
HttpURLConnection con;
InputStream is;
try{
    con=((HttpURLConnection)new URL(app_url).openConnection());
    con.setRequestProperty("Cookie",cookie);
    is=con.openStream();
    //recv code
}finally{
    if(is!=null){try{is.close();}catch(IOException e){}}
    if(con!=null){try{con.close();}catch(IOException e){}
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, this works. In addition, to "allow_redirects=False" in Java you should do the following: `con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);` (Unrelated to cookies, but since it was included as part of the parameters).

Comment: I think it is set to false by default.

Answer (score 0):

The typical solution is using Apache HttpClient. If you need a less engineered and/or third-party library free solution, I'd suggest `URLConnection` or the new Java 11 `HttpClient`.

```java
private final CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

...

public String get(String appUrl, String cookie) {
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(appUrl);
    request.setHeader("Cookie", cookie);

    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request)) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        return EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java11's [`HttpClient`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) it could look like follows:

```
HttpResponse<String> response = HttpClient.newBuilder()
    .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.NEVER)
    .build()
    .send(
        HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create(url))
            .header("cookieName", "cookieValue")
            .GET()
            .build(),
        HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume you can reliably do the request. If not, this could help you.

[How to get HTTP response code for a URL in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467848/how-to-get-http-response-code-for-a-url-in-java/6467904)

To handle cookies, you may want to look at this

[How to set Cookies at Http Get method using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249137/how-to-set-cookies-at-http-get-method-using-java)

Both implementations use the basic Java HttpURLConnection class.

Comment: This are 2 links and this is no answer. Please try to explain it.